# Compare the key with array of dictionaries in iOS swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift4

I am trying to  compare the studentId with the array of dictionaries which has multiple studentId's. I need to get the dictionary which matches with the particular StudentID..Can any one please suggest the perfect solution. I am new to swift.

```
"students" : [
    {
      "studentId" : "STUDENT123456789",
      "middleName" : "Evangeline",
      "firstName" : "Dia",
      "rollNo" : "1001",
      "studentClass" : {
        "className" : "Grade 10",
        "classId" : "CLASS123456789",
      }
    }
  {
      "studentId" : "STUDENT14354678960",
      "middleName" : "Joseph",
      "firstName" : "Parker",
      "rollNo" : "1002",
      "studentClass" : {
        "className" : "Grade 10",
        "classId" : "CLASS15468975467",
      }
    }
  ]
```

I have students array which is an array of dictionaries.Now I have to compare student Id with this existing array containing multiple studentID's. so when it matches with the student ID, I need to get that particular dictionary data.
For example, I have studentId as "STUDENT14354678960" so I need to get the data containing related to this Id..

Answer (score 3):

Use `first`, it returns the first found object or `nil`

```
if let student = students.first(where: {$0["studentId"] as! String == "STUDENT123456789"}) {
   print(student["firstName"])
} else {
   print("not found")
}
```

---

It's highly recommended to use a custom struct or class for the student data for example

```
let jsonString = """
{"students" : [
{"studentId" : "STUDENT123456789", "middleName" : "Evangeline", "firstName" : "Dia", "rollNo" : "1001", "studentClass" : { "className" : "Grade 10", "classId" : "CLASS123456789"}},
{"studentId" : "STUDENT14354678960", "middleName" : "Joseph", "firstName" : "Parker", "rollNo" : "1002", "studentClass" : {"className" : "Grade 10", "classId" : "CLASS15468975467"}}
]}
"""

struct Root : Decodable {
    let students : [Student]
}

struct Student : Decodable {
    let studentId, middleName, firstName, rollNo : String
    let studentClass : StudentClass
}

struct  StudentClass : Decodable {
    let className, classId : String
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    let students = result.students
    if let student = students.first(where: {$0.studentId == "STUDENT123456789" }) {
        print(student)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Actually, I am storing the students data in UserDefaults and getting by using key ..                                                                                               let defaults = UserDefaults.standard.            
let studentData = defaults.value(forKey: "ClassStudents") as! Data.             
let studentsArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: studentData) as! NSArray

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` in Swift, you are throwing away the type information, use `[[String:Any]]`

Comment: oh ok Thanks! I changed to [String:Any] ..So where the above solution can fit into mine. I don't have jsonString. Should I convert the [String:Any] to string type?...It showing me error "Value of type [String:Any]"has no member "utf8"

Comment: The data type in the question is JSON so I assumed that you retrieved the data from  the network. You could convert the dictionary to JSON with `JSONSerialization` and then decode into the structs.

Comment: Hmm yeah! I have retrieved data from network and I am storing the data  in userDefaults in the form of  NSKeyedArchiver by giving a key name and getting the data by NSKeyedUnarchiver in another view..I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJson

Answer (score 2):

You can use where with a closure:

```
let search = students.first { (element) -> Bool in
    if let dict = element as? [String:Any] {
        return dict["studentId"] == yourID
    }
}
```

Comment: It is showing me error "Type Any has no subscript members" near return dict

Comment: How do you declare your array?

Comment: Actually, I am storing the dictionary in user defaults by giving a key and getting by using NSKeyedUnarchiver

Comment: @HarryP you need to set the type of data in your array and dictionnary, see my edited anwser